# scp: illegal option -- 0

Tags: scp

I am trying to copy data over shh connexion to a distant server.

I get the following error:

```
[localhost]: scp: illegal option -- 0
[localhost]: usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
[localhost]: [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
[localhost]: [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

The script that i used perform this request:

```
 scp -p10012 /Users/trst/Docs/repositories/pro/.envoydeploy/tmp/servers/172.12.11.150 admin@172.12.11.150:/var/www/pro/tmp/service_owner
```

Answer (score 8):

The switch for setting a port in scp is an upper-case `-P`

```
 -P port
         Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that
         this option is written with a capital ‘P’, because -p is already
         reserved for preserving the times and modes of the file in
         rcp(1).

 -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the
         original file.
```

Lower-case `-p` doesn't take an argument, hence `10012` is being treated as a further sequence of options; options `-1` and `-2` are valid options (controlling the SSH protocol) but `-0` isn't - hence the error.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, i use the following script (https://github.com/nickfan/envoy-deployscript/blob/master/Envoy.blade.php) to deploy my app. The error is produced at line 583 where script use the -p flag for specifying the port.. I don't well understand the problem..

Comment: It would appear there's an error in that script. Submit a pull request changing that `-p` to `-P`.